# PTIJ: How to refrain from killing Amalekites and still be a good Jew

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

We are commanded to destroy the descendants of Amalek.

Haman was a descendant of Amalek.

On Purim, we must get so drunk we can't tell Haman from Mordechai.

Does that mean that, if I don't want to kill anybody and still be a good Jew, I must be drunk all the time?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, yes. You should get drunk, but only in private, not in a bar.

You still have an obligation to kill an Amalekite. But, you don't want anyone to know that it was you who did it. If you go into a bar, **everybody** knows your name.

Comment: Companion answer: Never kill an Amalekite in a bar.  Take it outside.